# Angular directive with multiple models

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, models

I am creating a angular js keyboard directive that must be reusable and must have dynamic template. I found some tutorials and I am able to come up with this code

```
angular.module('formApp').directive('keyboard',
    function ($compile, $http, $templateCache, config) {

    var getTemplate = function (keyboardType) {
        var templateLoader,
        baseUrl = config.baseUrl + 'Scripts/controls/keyboard/',
        templateMap = {
            defaultKeyboard: 'default.html',
            numeric: 'numeric.html',
            //add more here
        };

        var templateUrl = baseUrl + templateMap[keyboardType];
        templateLoader = $http.get(templateUrl, { cache: $templateCache });

        return templateLoader;

    }

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var loader = getTemplate(attrs.type);

        var promise = loader.success(function (html) {
            element.html(html);
        }).then(function (response) {
            element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '='
        },
        link: linker
    };
});
```

Sample implementation

```
<keyboard type="defaultKeyboard"></keyboard>
```

I think i will never have a problem if I only have one text input since i can bind the model to the directive (not yet implemented), but what if the form will have several input controls that uses the keyboard directive? How can the directive know which model to update?

[something similar to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKuiA.png)

I am thinking of creating a 'active' identifier that will be triggered when that input is clicked/selected so that the directive will know which model to update. Is this something doable in angular or are there much better/cleaner way?

Thanks

Comment: it's not really clear what this is supposed to do, much less what your issue is.  Since you used `scope:` on your directive, each instance of the directive will be isolated from every other instance, so what you are describing (multiple input controls, knowing which to update) wouldn't be relevant, since each use of the directive wouldn't have access to any other input control anyway.

Comment: @Claies Apology for the unclear info. The directive code is not yet complete. About the multiple input control, imagine a form with 5 text boxes and at the bottom there is the keyboard directive. When the focus is textbox1, when i type at the keyboard, it will update textbox1. Thanks

Comment: this sounds overly complex, to be honest.  So are you trying to design a 104key layout drawn in HTML that is comprised of buttons that somehow update a model inside the directive that in turn updates the model in a non-associated input somewhere else on the page? what's the point? why don't the normal keyboard options for the device work for your purpose?

Comment: to me, this sounds like something that will be very difficult to design and even more difficult to actually use, and doesn't really solve a practical issue.  Beyond that, it's not even something that is within the realm of design scenarios that angular is designed to help with.

Comment: I'm using a custom keyboard because i dont need all the 104 keys, basically just letters and number depending on the form that is why im using dynamic template. This is for a touch device (not mobile) and if I can just use a normal keyboard, I wouldnt ask here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I wish you luck in coming up with a workable solution, but the complexity of this endeavor you are describing is well beyond what angular would normally be used for.  Performance will likely be an issue with the number of event bindings necessary to monitor that many HTML elements....

Comment: Hi rodwin, I think you need to redesign it's logic. You can create a **attribute directive** and add this directive to each of your input. So, when you click on an input it should display your custom keyboard. Then you can simply listen each click in your keyboard and append it's value to your element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@` it will take value of directive. its batter to use attribute type directive in custom directives are.
Possible types of scope comparison

```
     scope: {
            type: '@type' //will take value for user as string
            type: '&type' // will except expression 
            type: '='     //match everthing
            type: '=type'   //matchies scope valiable/object name
            }
```

Comment: Im using the 'type' for me to know what type of keyboard layout i want to use. So far i dont have issue with that. However, I am now in the step of updating the model when the keyboard is clicked. Imagine a form with 5 text boxes and at the bottom there is the keyboard directive. When the focus is textbox1, when i type at the keyboard, it must update textbox1 as well as its model. Same with textbox2,3,4,5. Thanks